# Excel Filter not updating

Tags: excel, filter

I have a worksheet called 'data' which contains various entries that are then referenced on other worksheets.

In `data R1` I have a filter that doesn't seem to be updating when I use VBA to update the worksheet.
The filter is:

```
=FILTER( Sites!C:C & " - " & Sites!B:B, LEFT(Sites!C:C, 2) = "NW")
```

If I update the Sites worksheet manually, the new results are seen by the filter. But if I use VBA to update the Worksheet the filter doesn't show the new results.

This is how I'm updating the Sites worksheet

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sites").Cells(destRow, 2) = valA
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sites").Cells(destRow, 3) = valB
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sites").Cells(destRow, 4) = valB
```

Should updating the worksheet as above update the filter ? It appears to either revert to empty or use the last values.

I'm not sure if this matters in my VBA I have

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.CalculateBeforeSave = False
```

How do I get the filter to update correctly ?

Thanks

Comment: `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` - yes this does matter, since you've turned automatic calculation of formulas off.

Comment: And with save off, you won't keep the new results after closing it.

Comment: Thanks. Commented out both entries and that does allow it to work. But the updating of the worksheet is taking much longer. Is there any way to keep this in, and then force the filter to update ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.CalculateBeforeSave = False
```

do matter; they've disabled automatic calculation and also turned off calculation before saving.

You may be able to just call `Calculate` on a specific sheet or range:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Calculate
```

or

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Rows(1).Calculate
```